# Dojo and prototype based inheritance

Tags: javascript, dojo, prototypal-inheritance

I've been used to creating dojo AMD modules as part of my rich internet application, using the following structure -

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function(declare, Button){
    return declare(null, {
        label:"",
        constructor: function(label){
            this.label = label
        }
    });
});
```

Which is fine, though now I need to include some prototype based inheritance in order to extend a `Command` object for writing functional tests in `intern`.  I am using the following example in - https://theintern.github.io/intern/#writing-functional-test  It shows to extend the `Command` object by writing -

```
function CustomCommand() {
  Command.apply(this, arguments);
}
CustomCommand.prototype = Object.create(Command.prototype);
CustomCommand.prototype.constructor = CustomCommand;
CustomCommand.prototype.login = function (username, password) {
  return new this.constructor(this, function () {
    return this.parent
      .findById('username')
        .click()
        .type(username)
        .end()
      .findById('password')
        .click()
        .type(password)
        .end()
      .findById('login')
        .click()
        .end();
  });
};
```

How and where does this get plugged into my original class?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "parent" concept in `declare`. Inheritance via `declare` is mixing in properties into the prototype of an object. The first argument of `declare` is an array of objects to use as base prototypes. The second argument, your object that you pass, becomes the "immediate" (top level) prototype of objects created with the class returned by `declare`.

Basically, every time you create inheritance with `declare`, the properties of the parent classes get mixed into `this.prototype`, meaning they're accessible through `this`.

```
var Command = declare(null, {
    findById: function() {/* ... */},
    click: function() {/* ... */},
    type: function() {/* ... */},
    end: function() {/* ... */}
});

var CustomCommand = declare([Command], {

    click: function()
        // -- You can do whatever custom logic you want here specific to CustomCommand --

        // `inherited` is a special method that calls the parent's method.
        // This line calls the Command class's `click` method and returns the result:
        return this.inherited(arguments);
    },

    login: function(username, password) {
        // The prototype of "CustomCommand" contains all the methods defined by "Command".
        return this.findById('username')
            .click()
            .type(username)
            .end()
          .findById('password')
            .click()
            .type(password)
            .end()
          .findById('login')
            .click()
            .end();
    }

});

var customCommandInstance = new CustomCommand();
customCommandInstance.login();
```

And of course, you would separate these into different modules instead of doing it all in one file, so:

**my/Command.js**

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
    return declare(null, {
        findById: function() {/* ... */},
        click: function() {/* ... */},
        type: function() {/* ... */},
        end: function() {/* ... */}
    });
});
```

**my/CustomCommand.js**

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "my/Command"], function(declare, Command) {
    return declare([Command], {
        login: function(username, password) {
            // See above...
        }
    }); 
});
```

**main.js**

```
require(["my/CustomCommand"], function(CustomCommand) {
    var customCommandInstance = new CustomCommand();
    customCommandInstance.login();
}
```